# Exception when running PhoneGap0.9.6 application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

We have an PhoneGap application that runs perfectly okay when using the simulator but once running this in the actual iPhone connected to mac we get an exception (errors below). Note the application was working perfectly fine before upgrade to PhoneGap0.9.6/

```
objc[356]: Class Connection is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message and /var/mobile/Applications/D1D682A1-010B-4AE9-8761-4D553FCF8089/Frank151.app/Frank151. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
[Switching to process 13059 thread 0x0]
2011-07-08 18:00:45.355 Frank151[356:707] -[Connection initWithWebView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e4e0
2011-07-08 18:00:45.378 Frank151[356:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Connection initWithWebView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e4e0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x3166564f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35180c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x316691bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x31668649 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x315df180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   Frank151                            0x00017469 -[PhoneGapDelegate getCommandInstance:] + 164
    6   Frank151                            0x00002f7f -[AppDelegate getCommandInstance:] + 62
    7   Frank151                            0x00016807 -[PhoneGapDelegate deviceProperties] + 234
    8   Frank151                            0x00016475 -[PhoneGapDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:] + 28
    9   Frank151                            0x00003071 -[AppDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:] + 212
    10  UIKit                               0x318a9061 -[UIWebView webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:] + 244
    11  UIKit                               0x318a8427 -[UIWebViewWebViewDelegate webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:] + 22
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x316687a4 __invoking___ + 68
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x315e043d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 108
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x315e00d9 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 36
    15  WebKit                              0x345887bd -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 408
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x3166868d ___forwarding___ + 576
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x315df180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x316687a4 __invoking___ + 68
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x315e043d -[NSInvocation invoke] + 108
    20  WebCore                             0x36c39c3d _ZL11SendMessageP12NSInvocation + 16
    21  WebCore                             0x36cdcadf _ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 66
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x3163ca79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x3163e75f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 382
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x3163f4eb __CFRunLoopRun + 230
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x315cfec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x315cfdcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x30f4e41f GSEventRunModal + 114
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x30f4e4cb GSEventRun + 62
    29  UIKit                               0x316f5d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
    30  UIKit                               0x316f3807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    31  Frank151                            0x00002caf main + 78
    32  Frank151                            0x00002c5c start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
(gdb)
```

**UPDATE:** After not much luck after trying many things we decided to downgrade the application to PG 0.9.5.1 and it worked with no issues.  Not sure of the cause but something to do with PhoneGap 0.9.6 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Start by disabling any plug ins......

webView may be referring to ChildBrowser Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the info Randy.  Downgrading back to 0.9.5.1 ended up being the only viable answer after trying many different options.